# <!doctype html> width render issue input element

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when rendering my input text elements. If i add the `<!doctype html>` to my file the input element gets stretched, my input submit button does not.
I have tested in several different browsers and it is consistent, so it is probably me :(.

In the example my text element is rendered with a width of 304 pixels. When I remove the first line it will render at 300 pixels.

example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <STYLE type="text/css">
    *{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    input
    {
        width: 300px;
    }
 </STYLE>
<body>
    <input/><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know what is causing it, but more importantly how it can be fixed?

Comment: what doctype is that? I don't think it's valid. use the valid one.

Comment: @Headshota that's the [html5 doctype](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype)

Comment: @Headshota: its the standard html5 doctype

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you don't have that doctype, your page is rendering in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

In Quirks Mode, the `border` and `padding` of the `input` are counted *inside* the `300px` width.

When you add [the doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), your page is rendering in Standards Mode, and the `border` and `padding` are no longer part of the `300px` - that's where the "extra" `4px` is coming from.

See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

The easiest way to "fix" this for modern browsers is to use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing):

```
input
{
    width: 300px;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or, you can explicitly set the `padding` and `border-width` yourself, to make sure the sum of the values of `padding`, `border-width` and `width` add up to `300px`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the explination