# Why is <INPUT> wider than I told it to be?

Tags: html, css, html-select, html-input

Given a `<select>` and an `<input>` element, both specified to be **200px** wide:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<select style="width: 200px"></select><br/>
<input  style="width: 200px" type="text">
</body>
<html>
```

One ends up wider<sup>1,2,3, 4</sup> than the other:

[image]

What is the *reason* for this?

If someone can give the *reason*, perhaps the solution would be obvious, and not [a hack&pray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180647/how-to-line-up-html-input-elements).

### Layout

The applied layout is perfectly reasonable:

[image]

---

**Update 1**: While i was writing this question [Chrome updated itself from **17** to **19**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-infinite-version.html).

**Update 2:** Changing padding in the `<input>` from **1** to **zero**:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<select style="width: 200px"></select><br/>
<input style="width: 200px; padding: 0" type="text">
</body>
<html>
```

doesn't make the `<input>` **200px** wide (i.e. doesn't fix it).

**Update 3:** [Applying a CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125884/12597):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   * {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
   }
</style>
<body>
<select style="width: 200px"></select><br/>
<input style="width: 200px; padding: 0" type="text">
</body>
<html>
```

Does not solve the problem:

[image]

Also, i am less interested in a solution than an explanation.

### Footnotes

- <sup>1,2,3</sup> Chrome <strike>17</strike>19, Firefox, Internet Explorer 9
- <sup>4</sup> on Windows 7 64-bit

### Bonus Reading

- [How to make <option> wider than <select> in IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727635/how-to-make-option-wider-than-select-in-ie6) (i don't want the option to be wider than the select, i'm not using IE6)
- [How to show extended option in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700807/how-to-show-extended-option-in-select-list) (width of dropdown matches width of control)
- [HTML input element wider than Containing Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633522/html-input-element-wider-than-containing-div) (no containing `<div>` here)
- [How to line up HTML input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180647/how-to-line-up-html-input-elements)

Comment: What does the computed style show? any paddings?

Comment: Use a CSS reset and save yourself some pain.

Comment: set the same margin/padding for all

Comment: select elements use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> ### Your <input> isn't too wide; your <select> is too narrow!
>
> The real issue is that the `<select>` element **doesn't** behave like most elements do. It uses a
>
> ```
> box-sizing: border-box;
> ```
>
> where `width` is the width of the element ***after*** padding and borders are applied; behaving as though it alone were in *"quirks"* mode.
>
> This runs counter to every other standards mode html element, which use:
>
> ```
> box-sizing: content-box;
> ```
>
> To fix it, change the `<select>` to use the same box model as the rest of html:
>
> ```
> select { box-sizing: content-box; }
> ```
>
> OR change the `<input>` to use the same box model as the select:
>
> ```
> input { box-sizing: border-box; }
> ```

The input element behaves like most elements do, using a `content-box` model, where the `width` is the width of the element before padding and borders are applied.

There are default padding and borders set by your browser, so it is larger than you might want and/or expect. I always use a "CSS reset" at the top of my stylesheets, like so:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

That will ensure there are no default padding or margins on any element.

The `select` element is a different case though, where is behaves more like an element with `box-sizing: border-box` enabled, where it takes into account borders and padding into its `width` specification.

**If you add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `input` element, it will behave exactly as you expect/want.**

EDIT: Bolded the part that may be relevant to you. An alternate solution is reducing the specified `width` of the input element by a few pixels, so that it matches the width of the select box.

Fiddle demonstrating both solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/n4yT2/2/

Comment: Using `box-sizing: border-box` is used to enable *Netscape/Quirks mode* when interpreting what a `width` means. CSS dictated that a `width` would no longer specify the **width** of a box, but the **width** of stuff *in* the box. This would seem to indicate that `<select>` is behaving exactly as it should, and the `<input>` is the one that is wrong (i.e. just cause i told it to be `200px` wide doesn't mean it should **be** 200px wide). So, really, i should be applying `box-sixing: content-box` to the **input**. Either way, it doesn't explain *why* removing all padding/borders doesn't work.

Comment: `content-box` is the default `box-sizing` property for most elements, where is specifies the width of the "stuff within the box." `border-box` specifies the total width of the element, which is what the `select` element uses by default, which is why its true width is 200px when you specify the CSS width to be 200px.

Comment: *"`content-box` is the default `box-sizing` property"*  Except on in `<select>` element. i was accusing the `<input>` of knocking over the lamp, when really it's the `<select>` who's being bad.

Comment: No, your browser is just applying a default border and padding to the input element. If you set `style="border: 0; padding: 0; width: 200px;"` on the `input`, its "true" width will be 200px. If you add a 2px border to both sides, its true width will be 204px. This is how the `content-box` model works.

Comment: Ah okay, saw the edit to your comment from when you originally posted it backward. You got it now, yeah.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. i had it *completely* backwards. i scrolled up to my diagram, and realized i'd screwed it up.

Comment: @IanBoyd Are you sure the big title you added to this answer is correct? I thought you were claiming the input was too wide, and that the select box was the right size.

Comment: Oh for gods sake i did it again. Just shoot me. :(   The *header* part was wrong, but the guts were right.

Comment: This just solved the problem I was having so thank you! don't forget to use the relevant vendor prefixes though:   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 3):

It all goes back to Netscape.

It's amazing how many people think the IE box model was:

- broken
- broken by Microsoft
- [broken in IE6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)

It's even funnier that:

- [the box model that Netscape created](http://www.jefftk.com/p/the-revenge-of-the-ie-box-model) was objectively *"right"* *([archive](https://archive.fo/XPv7E))*
- when the W3C decided to standardize a box model, they chose a box model that was  objectively *"wrong"*
- they chose a box model that no browser was doing, and that no web-site was using

Netscape and IE had already agreed that if you tell something to be 200px wide: it was going to be 200px wide. People then had to live with the strangeness of that nonsensical W3C box model, e.g.:

- you tell something to be to be `200px` wide, and in a standard conforming browser it will be `204px` wide
- you tell a `select` to be `200px` wide, and in a standard conforming browser it will be `200px` wide

### HTML5 finally fixes the W3C broken box model

It is so strange that a 200px wide item doesn't end up being 200px wide, that in HTML5 we finally have the ability to return to the original (correct) Netscape/IE box model:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

Where a button `75px` wide is `75px` wide.

- Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/argxojcp/

[image]

```css
* {

}

td {
}

.correct {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th></th><th>Correct</th><th>W3C</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>text input</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="correct" style="width: 100px;">
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>select</td>
        <td><select class="correct" style="width: 100px;">foo</select>
        <td><select style="width: 100px;">foo</select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>button</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="correct" style="width: 100px;">
        <td><input type="button" style="width: 100px;">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>image</td>
        <td><input type="image" class="correct" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <td><input type="image" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>password</td>
        <td><input type="password" class="correct" style="width: 100px;">
        <td><input type="password" style="width: 100px;">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>submit</td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="correct" style="width: 100px;">
        <td><input type="submit" style="width: 100px;">
    </tr>   
    

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because browsers do things with the dimensions of input boxes (adding default borders, padding, changing box sizing, etc) to match them to their (or the operating system's) native GUI control equivalents.

The hack-and-pray solution, though, is the obvious one, unfortunately.

Comment: Updated question to include this is on Windows (7 (64-bit (Professional)))

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `<select>` elements behave like they had `box-sizing: border-box`. Trying to change it to `box-sizing: content-box` doesn't work, though (at least on Chrome 19, OSX 10.7.4).

After you applied the CSS reset, the size difference remains due to the borders on the input box. If you remove them, both elements will be exactly 200px wide. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UDjP5/).

Comment: And now that i know the answer, it's easy to google for (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450587/inconsistent-box-model-between-input-type-submit-and-input-type-text)